# In TypeScript, if an inline function takes an argument that is of a generic type, how do I "get" the type parameter from it?

Tags: typescript, types, syntax, typescript-generics

Here's what I'm trying (not working):

```
interface I<T = any> {
    value: T
}

// Doesn't work, "Cannot find name 'T'."
const foo = (i: I<T>): T => {
    return i.value;
}
```

I've tried various places to stick `<T>` in and around the method definition to try to get a new type variable name, but with no luck. Here's what *does* work, using `function` syntax:

```
interface I<T = any> {
    value: T
}

function foo<T> (i: I<T>): T {
    return i.value;
}
```

Is there an equivalent syntax for inline/fat-arrow functions?

Comment: `const foo = <T>(i: I<T>): T => i.value;`

Comment: btw, note [IntelliSense will tell you this if you want](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIB4AqyC8y4gCeAfMgN4BQy1yAbnADYCuEAXMphQL4UUxMgEYYAHsQyGCJFZSACmDsMmYgEp22SjWRQIYJlHHAAdPWYQA3N15hCABxQAxKbmQ37ImBKnnkAel-IAKoAziio4BAMDMAAyhAgochiyE4iFP6udo7OeDLyijIquKSYQA)

Comment: Thanks! Nice idea, jcalz. Unfortunately, this syntax produces an error in a .tsx file, which is part of why I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Interesting... I guess you could do `const foo: <T>(i: I<T>) => T = i => i.value;`

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15713